# cabal build fails when increasing version numer

Tags: cabal

I have updated the version number on a module from `0.1.5.6` to `0.1.5.7` and the build (`cabal build`) fails with with the error message:

```
uniform-latex2pdf.cabal is up-to-date
Resolving dependencies...
Error: cabal: Could not resolve dependencies:
[__0] next goal: uniform-latex2pdf (user goal)
[__0] rejecting: uniform-latex2pdf-0.1.5.7 (`)
[__0] rejecting: uniform-latex2pdf-0.1.5.6, uniform-latex2pdf-0.1.5.2,
uniform-latex2pdf-0.1.5.1 (constraint from user target requires ==0.1.5.7)
```

How should I read this? I understand that the target of this build is `0.1.5.7`. Why is it then rejecting uniform-latex2pdf-0.1.5.7 and claiming `constraint from user target requires ==0.1.5.6`?

What can I change to have the build succeed. I have already removed the `dist-newstyle` folder to no avail.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "updated the version number"? Do you have a link to a repository so that I can try to reproduce it?

Comment: I bumped the version numer up by one.... I got into a similiar problem and got an explanation in `https://github.com/haskell/cabal/issues/9021`; it seemed that my lack of understanding of GHC built ins and cabal freeze lead to the error message confusing me.  I still think the error message could be improved, but understand now the cause a bit better. Thank you for trying!